# Timeline graph for version control systems

Tags: version-control, data-visualization

I search for an timeline graph for version control systems (like git, svn, cvs, ...) with its creation dates, ancestors and versions. I've found nothing like that.

If there is no such graph, what tool can I use to create such graphs like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Web_development_timeline.png/800px-Web_development_timeline.png) or [this](http://futurist.se/gldt/wp-content/uploads/subtrees/knoppix1010.png)?

**Edit**: I've made one for myself: https://aaron-fischer.net/zed

[image]

Comment: This question does not seem to be appropriate for this statistics stackexchange. Maybe you could move it to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you look into:

- [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), for visualizing graphs, and which has a variety of incarnations. First choice, very flexible language that should let you do what you want with a little programming to automate generating the graphs. (Including things like the dotted lines from your first example.
- [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/), which is a library for R, Python, etc for working with
  (and visualizing) graphs.
- [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), network (in the graph theory) analysis.
- [gephi](http://gephi.org/), which is similar to cytoscape.
- Also consider mind-mapping software like Freemind, Xmind, etc.

In all cases, these tools can display the hierarchical network that describes your data, though adding dates/times might be difficult. (Graphviz lets you place nodes exactly where you want, so you might add the time scale in another program. In any case, you'd need to do some programming to munge the actual VCS data into something graphable.)

Answer (score 0):

A suitable graph for your requirement is called ***Sankey*** chart.

It is usually used to describe flow and transitions. It can be adapted to show source control revisions. You can use the width of the line to present the number of line codes changed, and colors to present different release version etc.

[image: example of energy flow]

Another nice implementation for this is [evolines](http://code.google.com/p/evolines/).
[image]

Another option that is a bit simpler is using a ***SpaceTree*** like the one InfoViz (http://thejit.org/). Check their demo below:

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

[image]